# Connection reset in test using REST-assured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I have a test with the use of REST-assured. In this test when I pass full host and path to get() method, everything goes fine, test passes. But when I try to use RestAssured.baseURI and RestAssured.basePath like it's shown in this part of the tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Default_values, test ends up with Connection reset. Below I paste working version and version with baseURI which doesn't work, and the error I get. Help please :>

Working version:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Iterator;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.basic;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;

public class SomeTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "provideData")
    public void doSomeTest(String someParameter, String someExpectedValue) {

        given().
                auth().basic("login", "pass").
                param("someParameter", someParameter).
        when().
                get("http://some.host/some-base-path/some-path-relevant-in-test").
        then().
                statusCode(200).
                body("some json", containsString(someExpectedValue)).
                log().ifError();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "provideData")
    public Iterator<Object[]> provideData() {

        //this provides data for test method in irrelevant way
    }

}
```

Not working version which results in Connection reset:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Iterator;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.basic;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;

public class SomeTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "provideData")
        public void doSomeTest(String someParameter, String someExpectedValue) {

        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://some.host";
        RestAssured.basePath = "/some-base-path";

        given().
                auth().basic("login", "pass").
                param("someParameter", someParameter).
        when().
                get("/some-path-relevant-in-test").
        then().
                statusCode(200).
                body("some json", containsString(someExpectedValue)).
                log().ifError();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "provideData")
    public Iterator<Object[]> provideData() {

        //this provides data for test method in irrelevant way
    }
}
```

Error:

```
mar 19, 2014 10:26:01 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
mar 19, 2014 10:26:01 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: hi Barbra How did you fix the issue? I have the same situation here, connection rest on specific restful calls while serializing entities.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making many requests in a short amount of time? You could try [closing idle connections after each request](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Connection_Config) and/or [reuse the HTTP Client instance](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#HTTP_Client_Config) for multiple requests.

Comment: Actually as it is a poc this is whole my code at the moment except from that data providing part so I don't make many request. But I added the config that you mentioned. Unfortunatelly it didn't change anything but thank you anyway :) Maybe I set baseURI and/or basePath in a wrong manner but following the documentation I can't figure out how else I should do this to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Restassured fixed on version 2.8.1. 
There was a leakage of resources, connections weren't closed. See https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/633.